# I am trying to stop a specific method thats being played when the user moves on

Tags: java, methods, audio-player

I am making a game, a jeopardy game to be specific, and in the game I have background noises so for example if the user gets a question right, a ding noise plays and the crowd cheers. It's not a huge game breaking issue however I would like to know if theres any way to stop the noise if the user clicks "ok" in the prompted JOptionPane. I would also like to state that I am very new to coding.

I've tried searching up how to stop the file thats being played however I couldnt find anything so if anyone knows how to make it so either the file thats being played can be stopped or the method in which the file is held in itself can be stopped that would be great.

```
package testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import static java.awt.Font.BOLD;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class testing implements ActionListener{

    static String Choice;       


    static String[][] Questions = {{"The Raptor is the mascot for which basketball team"}};

    static String[][] Answers = {{"Toronto Raptors"}};

public  JButton[][] t = new JButton[5][5];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new testing();
    }

static int n = 100;

public testing() {

    JFrame scoreframe = new JFrame("SCORE");
    scoreframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    scoreframe.setSize(400,250);
    scoreframe.setVisible(true);

    JFrame gameframe = new JFrame("Jeopardy");
    gameframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    gameframe.setSize(1920,1080);
    gameframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 4));


    for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
            String vakue = String.valueOf(n);
            t[r][c] = new JButton(vakue);
            t[r][c].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            t[r][c].setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            t[r][c].putClientProperty("rows", r);
            t[r][c].putClientProperty("columns", c);
            t[r][c].setFont(new Font("Swis721 BlkEx BT", BOLD, 40));
            t[r][c].addActionListener(this);
            gameframe.add(t[r][c]);
        }
        n = n +300;

        gameframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void crowd() {

      try {
       File file = new File( "crowd.wav");
       Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
       clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
       clip.start();

      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
     }

public static void applause() {

      try {
       File file = new File( "Applause.wav");
       Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
       clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
       clip.start();

      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
     }

public static void check() {

      try {
       File file = new File( "check.wav");
       Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
       clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
       clip.start();

      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
     }

@Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton A = new JButton();
    A = (JButton) e.getSource();
    int rows = (int) A.getClientProperty("rows");
    int cols = (int) A.getClientProperty("columns");
    Choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, Questions[rows][cols]);
    String score = A.getText();
  A.addActionListener(this);

    if (Choice.equalsIgnoreCase(Answers[rows][cols])) {
         check();
         applause();
         crowd();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That's right! The correct answer was: " + Answers[rows][cols]+"! \nYou win " + score + "$");

            A.setEnabled(false);
    }    
}
}
```

I narrowed my code down so if anyone attempts to try it in their program they dont have to deal with anything extra. Basically, I broke my code down to show the issue, i'm aware you wont be able to hear the sounds however for helping purposes, let's just say the sounds were all 10 minutes long (they aren't really but lets say they are) if you run my code and click the first button in position 1,1 it will ask u what basketball team the raptor is a mascot for, so when you input the answer ("Toronto Raptors") a message appears telling the user they got the question right and how much money they earn, as this happens the 10 minute music is playing in the back. They click "ok" and the music remains in the back for the entire sound track, how can i make it so when the user clicks "ok" the sounds stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you would like to hold a reference to the current clip (doesn't matter whether it is actually playing right now or not). For this, create a static variable holding the clip. Then define `play` and `stop` functions, when each `play` will first try to `stop`. In addition, it is better to NOT copy and paste the same code in different functions:

```
private static Clip clip = null;

public static void stop() {
    if (clip != null) {
        clip.stop();
        clip = null;
    }
}

public static void play(String toPlayName) {
    stop();
    File toPlay = new File(toPlayName);
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(toPlay));
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void crowd() {
    play("crowd.wav");
}

public static void applause() {
    play("Applause.wav");
}

public static void check() {
    play("check.wav");
}
```

Comment: wow this makes everything so much simpler! Thank you very much!